# Display gets too glitchy when Tor connection is active on Tails

Tags: debian, tor

I'm connecting using Tails 4.9/Tor to internet on my old 13" Retina macbook pro.

Without the connection, I'm not having any issues on display but as soon as I connect to WiFi, the display starts to glitch.
The display keeps distorting and flickers while the screen is changing. If I disconnect, all these problems are gone.

Is this a common issue? I couldn't find any solutions to this or any mention of it. I tried adding boot loader arguments on GRUB but I don't think they take any effect. (I tried nouveau.noaccel=1)

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! That sounds like a really uncommon issue. Could you provide some screenshots of the flickering? I find it hard to believe that Tor is causing such an issue. It might just be that you need to install some macbook specific graphics drivers.

Comment: Thanks. 

Unfortunately, the problem doesn't appear on screenshots. The closest photo I could find on the internet is this one: [link](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.zdfpO9vE5Ckqe0lh_6xNJQHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1)
This really looks like a hardware problem, but the weird thing is that the moment I turn off the connection, the problem gets fixed.

Comment: Btw, I installed all updates from synaptic package manager but I'm not sure if that's comprehensive enough.

Comment: I guess you already checked that it's not under the known graphics issues here: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/graphics/index.en.html

Comment: I'm not too sure that's the cause, but the system clock is only synchronized when connected to tor. Might be related. Source: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html

Comment: Also from the known issues:
On some computers, Tor Browser and Thunderbird are displayed incorrectly:

The application window is initially empty and white.
The icons and menus only appear when hovered by the mouse.
The contents of the window is only displayed in stripes when scrolling.
To workaround this issue, add the following boot option when starting Tails:

`intel_iommu=off`